# Regex to match exact word with Kiama Parser in Scala

Tags: regex, parsing, scala

I am looking for the correct regex form to give to my Kiama Packrat Parser in order that when it encounters keywords like `int` it recognises this is a type, and not a valid var name.

At present I have :

```
    lazy val type_int_ =  ".*\\bint\\b.*".r ^^ (s => TypeInt)


lazy val var_ =
    idn ^^ TermVar 


  lazy val idn =
    "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*".r
```

But this does not work, so I would appreciate pointers on this.

Many thanks

Comment: What is this for a question? "this does not work" is not a good error description. Furthermore, could you please post a working example which produces the error and not only such meaningless lines of code?

Comment: If you have experience with kiama and Scala then all you would need to tell me is how I could construct the regex to achieve recognition of the word 'int' alone. The context within which the code sits is irrelevant!

Comment: While your first sentence is true, it still makes it harder for people having experience with regexes but not with Kiama to answer your question. In the end it is you who is looking for a solution.

Comment: A kiama-specific solution is the crux of the problem

Comment: Then you are probably better of asking the questio on the mailing list, Tony usually replies quite quickly. You can still post an answer here and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've successfully used the following approach:

```
val keyword = regex ("int[^a-zA-Z]".r)

val identifier = not (keyword) ~> "[a-zA-Z]+".r
```

In other words, recognise the keyword only if it's not followed by a character that can extend it to be an identifier. A downside is that the extension regexp is repeated in both the keyword definition and the identifier one, but that can be factored out if you want.

You've got to be a bit careful how you use the keyword parser, since it captures the character after the keyword as well. It's safe in the context of a `not`, since no input is consumed.

Note that whitespace usually does not need to be handled explicitly since the `literal` and `regex` parser combinators take care of it before they start parsing for what you really want.

This approach is easy to generalise to multiple identifiers, by writing a method to build the keyword parser from a list of the keyword strings and the extension regular expression.

BTW, Kiama doesn't really provide parsing combinators. We rely on the ones in the Scala library. We *do* provide some extensions of the standard ones for special situations, but the basic behaviour is just straight from the library. Thus, it's not clear to me that your question actually relates to Kiama at all. As mentioned in the comments above, including a self-contained example of the problem would help us be clearer about exactly which library you are using.

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed response. Are you involved in the kiama development then? Since posting this question I came across http://code.google.com/p/kiama/wiki/ParserCombs#Tokens but the approach you describe is different?

Comment: Yes, I'm the lead Kiama developer. That wiki page doesn't really get into the topic of avoiding clashes between keywords vs identifiers. The section you link to talks about parsing keywords by themselves, which is a simpler problem. I'll make a note to add some discussion of the clash issue. Thanks for the nudge.

Comment: Wow, it's really great to talk with you! I've used Kiama for some academic work, specifically a System F Compiler, for which I found it very helpful so thank you! For a while I was tearing my hair out when it wasn't parsing how I expected, and then I realised when you have multiple rules separated by pipes, it seems to return the first match it finds. I had put simpler matches before complex compositions of those simpler matches so it was never recognising them! Worked it out eventually, and it really is a great lib :)

Comment: Great! Glad you like it.Yes, that ordering thing is a feature of parsing approaches based on parsing expression grammars, in contrast to ones based on context-free grammars where alternation is unordered.